# read.table imports text file as list, how to import it as a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I have some data in a text file, with columns v1, v2, v3, and v4. v1 contains alphanumeric data, while v2, v3, and v4 are numeric in nature.

I use the following command to read the data in R:

```
x <- read.table("file_name.txt", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

it imports the data, but I want it as a data frame, when I check the type using typeof(x), returns "list".

How to get this data into a data frame?

Comment: Are you sure it is not a dataframe? A dataframe is just a special type of list, you should run `class(x)` instead of `typeof(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

At first you can use `x1<-as.data.frame(x)`

Then you can use `class(x1)`.

If you will use `typeof(x1)` instead of `class(x1)`,
you will never get `"data.frame"`. Because `data.frame` is one type of `list` with an equal number of observations in each column which contain numeric, character, and alphanumeric variables same as a list.